# My python code won't give me other random numbers

Tags: python

My code keeps printing out the same numbers even thou i answer the question correctly.
This is supposed to be a math game were the code randomizes operations of 2 numbers that the user has to guess

```
import random

print("Enter A for addition:")
print("Enter B for subtraction:")
print("Enter C for multiplication:")
print("Enter D for division:")
print("Enter E for exit:")
options=str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))
                    
num1 = random.randrange(1, 21)
num2 = random.randrange(1, 21)

if options== 'E':
    print("Enter E(In caplocks to quit):")
    exit()


while options== 'A':
    real1=num1+num2
    print("What is",num1,"+",num2,":")
    answer_question=int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))
    if answer_question == (real1):
        print("You are correct!")
    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
```

Comment: How would I do that?, Like do i add it in the loop?

Comment: Move your random number generation into the while loop - I'll give you the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

print("Enter A for addition:")
print("Enter B for subtraction:")
print("Enter C for multiplication:")
print("Enter D for division:")
print("Enter E for exit:")
options=str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))
                    

if options== 'E':
    print("Enter E(In caplocks to quit):")
    exit()


while options== 'A':
    num1 = random.randrange(1, 21)
    num2 = random.randrange(1, 21)
    real1=num1+num2
    print("What is",num1,"+",num2,":")
    answer_question=int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))
    if answer_question == (real1):
        print("You are correct!")
    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time your while loop runs, you need to create two new random numbers. Since you originally had those numbers outside of your loop, they would never change they were outside of the ***scope*** of your while loop.

```
import random

print("Enter A for addition:")
print("Enter B for subtraction:")
print("Enter C for multiplication:")
print("Enter D for division:")
print("Enter E for exit:")
options = str(input("Hello,Please enter an option:"))

#num1 = random.randrange(1, 21) #Move these into your while loop
#num2 = random.randrange(1, 21) #Move these into your while loop

if options == 'E':
    print("Enter E(In caplocks to quit):")
    exit()

while options == 'A':
    num1 = random.randrange(1, 21) # <--
    num2 = random.randrange(1, 21) # <--
    real1 = num1 + num2
    print("What is", num1, "+", num2, ":")
    answer_question = int(input("Hello,Please enter an the answer to the question:"))
    if answer_question == (real1):
        print("You are correct!")
    else:
        print("You are incorrect!!!!")
```